# Shipping options depending on cart weight and shipping class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, isset

I am working on a WordPress site that uses WooCommerce. I found this piece of code that allows me to set a freight shipping option based on weight. It worked great until the client also wanted the same freight shipping option if a freight shipping class is selected on a product.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_tiered_shipping', 10, 2 );

function bbloomer_woocommerce_tiered_shipping( $rates, $package ) {

  if ( WC()->cart->cart_contents_weight < 300 ) {

    if ( isset( $rates['fedex:PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_2_DAY'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_GROUND'] ) );

  } else {

    if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:10'] ) ) unset( $rates['fedex:PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_2_DAY'],$rates['fedex:FEDEX_GROUND'] );
  }

return $rates;
}
```

Then I found another piece of code that could set a shipping class to a shipping option. The code I found was mean to `unset` shipping options that are available but I want to `isset` the freight shipping since we `unset` it via the cart weight. However, I am running into an issue where the freight shipping class can no longer be set to `isset` without causing major issues. Below is what I tried to do for the freight shipping.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'freight_shipping_class_only', 10, 2 );

function freight_shipping_class_only( $rates, $package ) {

  $shipping_class_target = 193;
  $in_cart = false;
  foreach( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
    if( $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_target ) {
      $in_cart = true;
      break;
    } 
  }
  if( $in_cart ) {
    unset( $rates['fedex:PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_2_DAY'],$rates['fedex:FEDEX_GROUND']  ); // shipping method with ID (to find it, see screenshot below)
    isset( $rates['flat_rate:10'] );
  }
  return $rates;
}
```

Is there a way to set both the cart weight and the freight shipping class in one function? It would be ideal since I want them both to do the exact same thing by `unset` all FedEx shipping option and `isset` the freight shipping option.

Let me know if you need me to be clearer or if you have any tips.

Thanks!

Comment: I have answered here as you can really simplify and merge your code in a unique function… Please have a look and your feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using 2 times the same hook, you can simply merge your functions in one.

> Now with php `[isset()][1]` you need to use it in as a condition in an `IF` statement to check if a variable is set (exist), but it has no effect alone outside your IF statement in your function.
>
> So in your first function the following doesn't has any effect:
>
> ```
> if ( isset( $rates['fedex:PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_2_DAY'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_GROUND'] ) );
> ```

So you can try this compact and efficient code instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'freight_shipping_class_only', 20, 2 );
function freight_shipping_class_only( $rates, $package ) {
    // HERE the targeted shipping class ID
    $targeted_shipping_class = 193;

    // Loop through cart items and checking
    $found = false;
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $targeted_shipping_class ){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    } 
    
    // The condition
    if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:10'] ) && ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() >= 300 || $found ) ){
        unset( $rates['fedex:PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_2_DAY'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_GROUND'] );
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it isn't exactly what I wanted but it works. What I did was change the cart weight to anything over 300 pounds `unset` the FedEx shipping options. Then `unset` FedEx shipping options for the freight shipping class. Which still left the freight shipping option visible on non-freight items, which I hid using CSS.

I am still open for a better way to do this. So if you have suggestions please send them my way.

Below is what I ended up doing.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_tiered_shipping', 10, 2 );

function bbloomer_woocommerce_tiered_shipping( $rates, $package ) {

if ( WC()->cart->cart_contents_weight < 300 ) {

    if ( isset( $rates['fedex:PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_2_DAY'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_GROUND'] ) );

} else {

    if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:10'] ) ) unset( $rates['fedex:PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_2_DAY'],$rates['fedex:FEDEX_GROUND'] );
}

 return $rates;
}

/** Freight Shipping Class Only **/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'freight_shipping_class_only', 10, 2 );

function freight_shipping_class_only( $rates, $package ) {
    $shipping_class_target = 193; 
    $in_cart = false;
    foreach( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        if( $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_target ) {
           $in_cart = true;
           break;
        } 
     }
     if( $in_cart ) {
        unset( $rates['fedex:PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT'], $rates['fedex:FEDEX_2_DAY'],$rates['fedex:FEDEX_GROUND']  );
     }
     return $rates;
}
```